# Default load DIV Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to build a navigation menu where one side is a male that you click on certain area's (ie the head) and on the left side its show the latest products, plus a break down of that section (shaving, razors, beard grooming etc)

My code can be seen here :

```
<section class="wr-our-brand">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="containerright">  
      <div id="building">
        <img src="images/nav_text.png"  alt="" usemap="#map" style="padding-top:4em;">    
        <map id="map" name="map">
          <area class="link" shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="69,3,127,31" data-val="one" target="" />
          <area class="link" shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="138,182,232,256" data-val="two" target="" />
          <area class="link" shape="rect" alt="" title="" coords="53,313,170,339" data-val="three" target="" />
        </map>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="containerleft">    
      <div  id="menu">
        <h2>Hello and Welcome</h2>
        <p style="font-size:16px;">Informational introduction Informational introduction Informational introduction Informational introduction Informational introduction Informational introduction. Informational introduction Informational introduction Informational introduction Informational introduction Informational introduction Informational introduction.<br><br> Informational introduction Informational introduction Informational introduction Informational introduction Informational introduction Informational introduction. Informational introduction Informational introduction Informational introduction Informational introduction Informational introduction Informational introduction.<br>
        <p style="font-size:16px;"><br>To view our wide range of products please select an area on the male outline.</p>

        <div class="tab" id="one">This is Hair</div>
        <div class="tab" id="two">This is two</div>
        <div class="tab" id="three">This is three</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Plus the Java Script here:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".link").click(function() {
        var which = $(this).data('val');
        $(".tab").hide();    
        $('#'+which).show();        
      });
    });
  </script>
```

My problem is that I wish for a welcome 'tab' to load without any user interaction (as seen in my code) however dissapear if the use clicks on another tab. At the moment it just sits there and the new information forms below it.

Cheers

UPDATE CSS

```
#building {
float: right;
} 
 #menu {
float: left;
width: 100%;
overflow: auto;

}
.tab { display:none; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should mark the `#menu` div as `position:relative` in your css and the tabs should be marked as `position:absolute` with `top:0` and `left:0`

Next to that, maybe you should put the welcome in a `separate` div as well and hide it when you open another tab (or make the welcome also a tab)

In this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3qhwwed1/) you can see it working with some modifications (I removed the image map, and put the welcome in a div)

Answer (score 0):

*I wish for a welcome 'tab' to load without any user interaction*

You can do this in css like:

```css
.tab {  display: none; }
```

The above css would make the tabs to hide but the welcome would be visible to user without any user interaction. But you need to make sure the `menu` div is not explicitly hidden via css.

Comment: Hi I already had that in the css however still have the same problem? would making a new .tab-deault etc work? If so what display etc would i need to add to it?